# A Lie group that has an immersion in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$ but no embedding?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

> **Question:** Is there a Lie group $G$ that admits a smooth immersion
>   $$i:G\longrightarrow\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$$
>   for some $n\in\Bbb N$, but *no* smooth embedding
>   $$j:G\longrightarrow\mathrm{GL}(m,\Bbb R)$$
>   for any $m\in\Bbb N$? (Here, $i$ and $j$ are also required to be group homomorphisms.)

The usual example of a Lie group which is immersed but not embedded is the group $\Bbb R$ with the immersion
$$i:\Bbb R\longrightarrow\mathrm{GL}(2,\Bbb C),\quad t\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}e^{it} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\alpha t}\end{pmatrix}$$
for $\alpha$ irrational. The so-called ***dense curve on the torus***. However, here $\Bbb R$ do embed in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$, but just in a different way:
$$j:\Bbb R\longrightarrow \mathrm{GL}(2,\Bbb R),\quad t\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

There are also well-known groups that have no injective homomorphism into $\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$, but then they do not immerse either.

Comment: To be clear: when you say "embedding" and "immersion" you want them also to be homomorphisms, and the "immersion" must be injective?

Answer (score 2):

There are countable groups (hence, Lie groups) $G$ such that there exists a faithful linear representation of $G$ but there is no faithful linear embedding of $G$. For instance, the 2-step solvable group
$$
G=BS(2,1)=< a,b: aba^{-1}=b^2>
$$
admits an injective homomorphism to $SL(2,R)$ but every injective homomorphism $f: G\to GL(n,R)$ will have non-closed image and, hence, will not be an embedding. The reason for the latter is that a discrete ebmedding $f: G\to GL(n,R)$ will (up to conjugation) land in the group $B$ of upper triangular matrices, but every discrete subgroup of $B$ is polycyclic (G.D. Mostow, On the fundamental group of a homogeneous space, Ann. of Math. (2) 66 (1957), 249–255), while $BS(2,1)$ is not polycyclic.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You could consider the simply connected covering of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. There are others too.

Comment: The question seems to be asking for a group with an _injective_ immersive homomorphism to $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ but no embedding.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: Yes, indeed, that seems to be so, thank you. I may just leave the answer alone for a while before I get a feedback from the OP.